# Hot to know which application is running in the screen?

Tags: android, android-service

I am doing an application that need a function to know which application is running in the screen.
I need my application to start a service, then when someone quit my application and run the other application, my application can know what the running application is.
Is there method that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, not for long.  You used to be able to do this with a hack, but Google broke that hack in Android 5.0.  Then someone discovered a new hack, but Google broke that hack in the M preview, which will probably become 5.2.  There is no known way to do this on M.  Google has clearly signaled their intention to prevent you from doing this, so even if another hack is discovered, you can count on it being broken as well.

M won't be out for a while, and won't have much market share for a while after that.  But don't write an app that requires this behavior if you need it to keep working for very much longer.